# How can I see events I saved to Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using a Firebase with my Android Studio project.

How the MainActivity should work:

1. User will pick a date in Calendar View.
2. After choosing the date, they will write their event in editText
3. After clicking the button, the event is saved to Firebase Realtime Database.
4. After clicking on the date where they wrote an event, it is supposed to be written in the same editText.

Users are unable to see their events after clicking the date. It just does not show up in the editText. Any idea why is that?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    TextView textViewLogOut, user_details, kalkulacka_go;
    FirebaseUser user;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    CalendarView calendarView;
    EditText editTextEvent;
    Button buttonSave;
    FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

    String stringDateSelected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        textViewLogOut = findViewById(R.id.textViewLogOut);
        user_details = findViewById(R.id.user_details);
        kalkulacka_go = findViewById(R.id.kalkulacka_go);
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        editTextEvent = findViewById(R.id.editTextEvent);
        buttonSave = findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Calendar");
        String userId = user.getUid();

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
                long selectedDate = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

                // get event for selected date from Firebase Realtime Database
                String key = String.valueOf(selectedDate);
                DatabaseReference eventRef = mDatabase.child("events").child(userId).child(key);
                eventRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        // set editText text to event for selected date, or "Please input event" if no event is found
                        String event = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        if (event != null) {
                            editTextEvent.setText(event);
                        } else {
                            editTextEvent.setText("Please input event");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        // handle error
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                long selectedDate = calendarView.getDate();

                // get event from editText
                String event = editTextEvent.getText().toString().trim();

                // save event for selected date to Firebase Realtime Database
                String key = String.valueOf(selectedDate);
                DatabaseReference eventRef = mDatabase.child("events").child(userId).child(key);
                eventRef.setValue(event);
                }
        });

        if(user == null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        else{
            user_details.setText(user.getEmail());
        }

        textViewLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        kalkulacka_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalculatorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I watched a ton of tutorials, I changed the rules of my Realtime Database. The code should be working but I had to make a mistake somewhere.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Well, I will try to explain as best as I can. Saving the event to selected date is working fine. But when I want to see the saved event on selected date. Nothing will show up but "Please input event". So my saved event is not showing. The console is not showing any errors.

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement it in a code. I'm newbie in Android Studio.

Comment: Now's a good time to learn [how to debug your code](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug).

Comment: These are the errors I got: 1. Target file doesn't exist: system/vendor/etc/sf_resolution_tuner_app_list.xml 2. ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument I see some accessing a hidden methor or waiting too long as well. Also I'm testing my app via my mobile phone (moto e6), not emulator.

Comment: Don't post the additional information (just) in comments please. Edit your question include a full [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite helpful).